# multiple sql joins not producing desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to sql and trying to tweak someone else's huge stored procedure to get a subset of the results. The code below is maybe 10% of the whole procedure. I added the lp.posting_date, last left join, and the where clause. Trying to get records where the posting date is between the start date and the end date. Am I doing this right? Apparently not because the results are unaffected by the change. UPDATE: I CHANGED THE LAST JOIN. The results are correct if there's only one area allocation term. If there is more than one area allocation term, the results are duplicated for each term.

```
SELECT Distinct
l.lease_id , 
l.property_id as property_id,
l.lease_number as LeaseNumber, 
l.name as LeaseName, 
lty.name as LeaseType,
lst.name as LeaseStatus,
l.possession_date as PossessionDate,
l.rent as RentCommencementDate,
l.store_open_date as StoreOpenDate,
msr.description as MeasureUnit,
l.comments as Comments ,
lat.start_date as atStartDate,
lat.end_date as atEndDate,
lat.rentable_area as Rentable,
lat.usable_area as Usable,
laat.start_date as aatStartDate,
laat.end_date as aatEndDate,
MK.Path as OrgPath,
CAST(laa.percentage as numeric(9,2)) as Percentage,
laa.rentable_area as aaRentable,
laa.usable_area as aaUsable,
laa.headcounts as Headcount,
laa.area_allocation_term_id,
lat.area_term_id, 
laa.area_allocation_id,
lp.posting_date
INTO #LEASES FROM la_tbl_lease l
INNER JOIN  #LEASEID on l.lease_id=#LEASEID.lease_id 
INNER JOIN la_tbl_lease_term lt on lt.lease_id=l.lease_id and lt.IsDeleted=0
LEFT JOIN la_tlu_lease_type lty on lty.lease_type_id=l.lease_type_id and lty.IsDeleted=0
LEFT JOIN la_tlu_lease_status lst on lst.status_id= l.status_id
LEFT JOIN la_tbl_area_group lag on lag.lease_id=l.lease_id
LEFT JOIN fnd_tlu_unit_measure msr on msr.unit_measure_key=lag.unit_measure_key
LEFT JOIN  la_tbl_area_term lat on lat.lease_id=l.lease_id and lat.isDeleted=0
LEFT JOIN  la_tbl_area_allocat_term laat on laat.area_term_id=lat.area_term_id and laat.isDeleted=0
LEFT JOIN dbo.la_tbl_area_allocation laa on laa.area_allocation_term_id=laat.area_allocation_term_id and  laa.isDeleted=0
LEFT JOIN vw_FND_TLU_Menu_Key MK on menu_type_id_key=2 and isActive=1  and id=laa.menu_id_key
INNER JOIN la_tbl_lease_projection lp on lp.lease_projection_id = #LEASEID.lease_projection_id 
where lp.posting_date <= laat.end_date and lp.posting_date >= laat.start_date
```

Comment: Without the tables definition and context, it's guessing only.

Comment: Though your left join and where condition both looks perfect but it would be very difficult to figure the exact problem like that. Also instead of left Join, try to use Inner join and see if you are getting the correct result.

Comment: Tried the Inner join but no luck.

Comment: **The code below is maybe 10% of the whole procedure**.  Hmm, think about that for a second ...

Answer (score 1):

Shorten it and copy it out as a new query in ssms or whatever you are using for testing. Use an inner join unless you want to preserve the left side set even when there is no matching lp.lease_id. Try something like

```
if object_id('tempdb..#leases) is not null
    drop table #leases;
select distinct
 l.lease_id  
,l.property_id as property_id
,lp.posting_date

into #leases
from la_tbl_lease as l
inner join la_tbl_lease_projection as lp on lp.lease_id = l.lease_id

where lp.posting_date <= laat.end_date and lp.posting_date >= laat.start_date 

select * from #leases

drop table #leases
```

If this gets what you want then you can work from there and add the other left joins to the query (getting rid of the select * and 'drop table' if you copy it back into your proc). If it doesn't then look at your Boolean date logic or provide more detail for us. If you are new to sql and its procedural extensions, try using the object explorer to examine the properties of the columns you are querying, and try selecting the top 1000 * from the tables you are using to get a feel for what the data looks like when building queries.  -Mike

Answer (score 1):

As may have already been hinted at you should be careful when using the WHERE clause with an OUTER JOIN.

The idea of the OUTER JOIN is to optionally join that table and provide access to the columns. 
The JOINS will generate your set and then the WHERE clause will run to restrict your set. If you are using a condition in the WHERE clause that says one of the columns in your outer joined table must exist / equal a value then by the nature of your query you are no longer doing a LEFT JOIN since you are only retrieving rows where that join occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the BETWEEN operator as well

```
Where lp.posting_date BETWEEN laat.start_date AND laat.end_date
```

Reasoning: You can have issues wheres there is no matching values in a table. In that instance on a left join the table will populate with null. Using the 'BETWEEN' operator insures that all returns have a value that is between the range and no nulls can slip in.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was easier to solve and it was in a different place in the stored procedure. All I had to do was add one line to one of the cursors to include area term allocations by date.